# elementByAccessibilityId - not working for latest react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, appium

`elementByAccessibilityId` doesn't return any data, throwing error:

> [elementByAccessibilityId("FOO")] Error response status: 7, , NoSuchElement - An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. Selenium error: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

```
  at Object.<anonymous>.exports.newError (node_modules/wd/lib/utils.js:152:13)
  at node_modules/wd/lib/callbacks.js:94:19
  at node_modules/wd/lib/webdriver.js:196:5
  at Request._callback (node_modules/wd/lib/http-utils.js:89:7)
  at Request.self.callback (node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
  at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
  at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
```

Tried to get the same element by `elementByXPath()`, which is working fine and returning data properly.

This should return the element by `accessbilityId` but NOT happening